# CSS, FAQ accordion icon text aligned horinzontal

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel ">
          <div class="accordion-toggle question-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent"#faqaccordion"="data-parent" #faqaccordion""="#faqAccordion" "" data-target="#question5">
            <h4 class="panel-title collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#question5">
              <a href="#" class="ing">Für welche Banken und Unternehmen ist der Bonitätsscore wichtig?</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="question5" class="panel-collapse collapse" >
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit][1] 
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.vr-box-section {
  @include mq-xsm {
    padding-left: 16px !important;
    padding-right: 16px !important;
  }
}

.container {
  @include mq-xsm {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

.panel {
  border-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.panel-group {
  padding-top: 24px;
}

.panel-heading {
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.ing:hover {
  color: #0066B3;
}

a.support {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.vr-box-section {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.panel-title:after {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\e113";
  float: left;
  color: black;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.2px white;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.panel-title.collapsed:after {
  content: "\e114";
}
```

I'm trying to implement a FAQ dropdown menu also with up/down toggle icons, on the left side. When I test the page on a small device looks like the text it's overlapping the icon. So I would like to locate the arrow and text on the same row, so I would look aligned and I can avoid the overlap. thanks

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgNT2.png)

Comment: just added a screenshot

Comment: Can you please post full code or snippet on codepen?

Answer (score 0):

If I truly understand the problem, This may help:

```
.panel-title {
   display: flex;
 }
```